# Form validation using angular

Tags: forms, validation, angularjs

i have a basic form . inside it , i have two fields(dropdown and textbox) whose behaviour is dependent on each other. I want to reset the textbox based on the change in dropdown. Also i want to add/integrate into the DOM as a new element so that validity etc can be taken care of which is to say i can use my $dirty to hide/show the message .

Comment: angular handles adding classes based on the validity of a field automatically. If you are simply trying to style based on $dirty/$valid then you can leverage those classes directly in your css (described here http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form). If you are trying to show an element based on validity then you can use the methods described here (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form.FormController) to monitor specific fields and their state. It would be soemthing along these lines ng-show="formName.fieldName.$dirty && formName.fieldName.$invalid"

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-model` and `$watch`

```
<select ng-model="dropdown" ng-options="**"><!-- --></select>
<textbox ng-model="textbox"></textbox>


$scope.$watch('dropdown', function () {
   $scope.textbox = '';
});
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch

Comment: This is not an ideal solution as if that dropdown scope variable is changed anywhere else it will reset the text field. That is unlikely in most cases but still not ideal. Angular provides a directive to track changes. Use ng-change='textbox=""' that handle the reset. If you are trying to change the text field to be the value of the selected option. Then simply bind them both to the same model. Or if you are wanting a more complex expression you can tie ng-change to a scope declared function that can handle the scope value changes.

Comment: @ntlarson True. However, from what I understood from the question, $watch would give the desired effect as the values are inner dependent, not the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. To have one value be dependant on another, just listen to the ng-change event of the first and then update the variable that the second one is bound to. eg:

   `$scope.selectChanged = function() {
       $scope.textValue = '';
   }`
2. To do validation, one approach I like to take is to have an "error" element declared and just show/hide it when needed.

Here's a quick snippet that illustrates both approaches
http://jsfiddle.net/marplesoft/ULhVS/